# With jQuery, how do I select an element with a meta-character in its name?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Let's say I have custom HTML tags like so:

```
<fb:est hours="5">5 Hours</fb:est>
<fb:act hours="4">4 Hours</fb:act>
```

How do I select the `fb:est` elements?

Doing `var e = $('fb:est')` does not work.  And `var e = $('fb\:est')` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> If you wish to use any of the
>   meta-characters
>   (#;&,.+*~':"!^$=>|/@ ) as a
>   literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two
>   backslashes: \. For example, if you
>   have an an input with name="names[]",
>   you can use the selector
>   $("input[name=names\[\]]").

So, this is the way to do it:

`var e = $('fb\\:est')`